# Can we do pipeline in lua script of redis

Tags: lua, redis

for example

I have several `set` commands, and I don't care the return value of them, in my lua script, I have to write several `redis.call('set', key, val)` .

Is there any way like pipeline, so I can do them together. Maybe more efficient？

Comment: Whenever you want to change something to be "more efficient", make sure of the two following things first: **Is there a performance problem to begin with ? Can I effectively measure performance before and after my change ?** Trying to optimize without being able to answer both those questions with **yes** is a waste of effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - there's no way to pipeline Redis calls from a Lua script, or batch them. Note that calling `redis.call` is very efficient so you shouldn't worry too much about that anyway.

As @deltheil pointed out, you can however "group" multiple calls to the same command if you use its variadic form. While of less importance for Lua scripts, this is definitely the recommend practice.

Comment: While correct this answer misses an important point: you can't pipeline from a LUA script because it doesn't make any sense. Redis LUA script execution is atomic and since Redis is single threaded, no other Redis command can be executed while a script is being executed anyway, making any need for pipelines in LUA scripts redundant and useless.

Comment: I think `redis.call` will definitely introduce some overhead, so that combining several calls into one should improve performance.

Comment: True, but the way that redis.call is implemented in Redis (i.e. with a fake client) makes supporting pipelining impossible... In any case the overhead of Lua/redis.call is surprisingly insignificant afair

Answer (score 5):

What about using [MSET](http://redis.io/commands/mset)?

```
$ redis-cli 
127.0.0.1:6379> eval 'redis.call("mset", "foo", "bar", "scm", "git", "test", "ok")' 0
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379> get foo
"bar"
127.0.0.1:6379> get scm
"git"
127.0.0.1:6379> get test
"ok"
```